# C# Pass data from While loop to other functions

Tags: c#, .net, function, while-loop, console-application

I have a Node.Js server running on localhost listening to some API requests.

These requests are transferred to my console application via TCP/IP. Here's my c# code which receives data from Node server (hosted at localhost:9999) via **GetData()** and pass it to another function **SendData()**.

```
namespace Datatransfer
{
    /* global variable declaration*/
    class Global
    {
        public static string receive_data;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static string HOST = "localhost";
        static int PORT = 9999;
        static TcpClient client;

      
        /*Function to receive data*/
        static string GetData()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                Global.receive_data= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Received data : " + Global.receive_data);
                SendData(Global.receive_data)
            }
        }

        /*Function to  send data*/
        static void SendData(string val)
        {
           /*Code to process recevied_data..*/
            Console.WriteLine("Data to Send : " + Global.receive_data);
           /*some codes....*/
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(HOST, PORT);
            GetData();
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have declared the **receive_data** as global so as to use it across the application. The code works and I am getting output. Everytime I make an API request to port 9999 am getting output as :

```
Connection Successfull...
Received data : somestring
Data to Send : somestring
```

I was wondering if this is an efficient way or not ?

Is there another way by which the **receive_data** can be passed to other functions **'without'** using the function ( ie;**SendData()** ) inside the **while** loop.? Or to put it simply, pass data from an infinite while loop to main or other functions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two options for further processing the data you receive:

1. Store it somewhere like you did (from a design perspective it doesn't matter how you implement this). Just one thing to think about would be if you want to store a list of received data-"messages", and what happens if you receive another message.
2. Call a method an pass the received data. This would be the better approach, because you abstract away the implementation and are free to change it (e.g. from storing global to a message-sink mechanism or whatever) without changing your receiving-code.

Approach 2) has more information and more context, because you trigger the method at the point you receive data. In option 1) you have no information about how old the information is, or even if the same information was sent multiple times. So more information is (always) better, if you don't need it in the method call, you are free to condense it again to say a global variable.

For approach 2) you should keep in mind, that the method is running "inside" your loop, so all long-running operations would block the loop. But still you are free to implement it in a way, that allows the message to be processed in another thread (asynchronous).